# how to set timeout feature in ember for AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

When we call a rest service via AJAX in ember, it takes a bit of time to process the data and create a PDF and return it to the frontend side.

By the time, the server process the PDF and return back, the webpage (from where the AJAX call is triggered) times out.

Please suggest how to set timeout feature in ember for ajax?

Below is ajax code from where the URL is triggered:

```
actions: {
  pdfClick(bookId) {
    const bookId = document.getElementById("version_"+bookId).value;
    const link1 = Globals.urlPrefix + this.get('router.url') + "?pdfdownload=pdfdownload&versionId=" + bookId;

    Ember.$.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      timeout:3000000,
      url: Globals.urlPrefix + this.get('router.url') + "/" + bookId
    }).then( respons => {
      const link = document.createElement('a');

      link.href = link1;
      link.download = 'book_' + new Date() + '.pdf';
      link.click();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you have already set timeout to 50 minutes, can you post the error message.

Comment: After 2 minutes, it gives the below error in the browser developer tool.


`(failed)
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Comment: I think you can check if your error is caused of timeout or something else. Checkout for this fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/u3f9C/

Comment: timeout is working fine with jquery but this code is in ember and in my case timeout is not working for Ember.$.ajax

Comment: consider it takes more than 2 min for response from server but after 2 min it gives above error, not waiting till the response

Comment: Your server might have timeout for 2 minutes. Maybe you should check for it.

Comment: NO but,in Ember is there any internal configuration for timeout in vendor.js or somewhere ?

Comment: `Ember.$` *is* `jQuery`! Actually Just use `jQuery.ajax` instead! Wont make any difference!

Comment: using jQuery.ajax also gives same error.. time out after 2 min..